# SQL: Greatest row with variable group / condition

Tags: sql, select, group-by, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I have this simplified table documenting some job runs:

```
+----+-----------------------+--------+
| id |          pit          |  stat  |
+----+-----------------------+--------+
|  1 | '2018-09-21 12:00:00' | 'TEST' |
|  1 | '2018-09-20 12:00:00' | 'TEST' |
|  1 | '2018-09-19 12:00:00' | 'PROD' |
|  1 | '2018-09-18 12:00:00' | 'PROD' |
|  1 | '2018-09-17 12:00:00' | 'TEST' |
|    |                       |        |
|  2 | '2018-09-19 14:00:00' | 'TEST' |
|  2 | '2018-09-18 14:00:00' | 'TEST' |
|    |                       |        |
|  3 | '2018-09-19 15:00:00' | 'PROD' |
|  3 | '2018-09-18 15:00:00' | 'PROD' |
|  3 | '2018-09-17 15:00:00' | 'TEST' |
|    |                       |        |
|  4 | '2018-09-21 12:00:00' | 'PROD' |
|  4 | '2018-09-20 12:00:00' | 'PROD' |
+----+-----------------------+--------+
```

Now i want to do the following:

For every id: Find the latest job-run. If the latest run has `stat = 'PROD'` then only return that row. If the latest run has `stat = 'TEST'` then return that row and additionally return the latest run with `stat = 'PROD'`.

Currently im running this SQL to get the most recent PROD-run as well as the most recent TEST-run for every id:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM SOME_TABLE t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(pit) pit, stat
    FROM SOME_TABLE
    GROUP BY id, stat
) mt ON t.id = mt.id AND t.pit = mt.pit
ORDER BY id asc, pit desc;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24aa1a/2)

Now what i'm missing is the part, that i want to filter out the runs with `stat = 'TEST'` if there is a more recent run with `stat = 'PROD'`.

Is there any good way of accomplishing this within the SQL?

Comment: `id=2` does not have value `PROD` for `stat` column. what should return for this id ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze In this case, only the most recent TEST-run should be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, rephrasing the requirement can help. Here, for each id, you want to return the most recent row, and the most recent "prod" row, which may or may not be the same row. An alternative way of looking at the problem is to sort the rows in two ways, and take the first row from each category:

1. In descending order by date (to get the most recent one), per ID
2. In ascending order by type (to get "prod" rows before "test" rows) and then in descending order by date, per ID:

```
SELECT id, pit, stat
FROM   (SELECT id, pit, stat
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY pit DESC) AS rn,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY stat ASC, pit DESC) AS prn
        FROM   some_table) t
WHERE  1 IN (rn, prn)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Rephrasing the requirement makes it more clear for me.
I will try this at Monday, when im at work again and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1):

```
 with tmp as (
          select SOME_TABLE.* from SOME_TABLE 
          inner join (Select MAX(pit) as pit,
          id from SOME_TABLE group by id) t on t.id = SOME_TABLE.id 
          and t.pit = SOME_TABLE.pit),
    tmp2 as(
          Select MAX(SOME_TABLE.pit) as pit, SOME_TABLE.id, SOME_TABLE.stat 
          from SOME_TABLE 
          inner join tmp on tmp.id = SOME_TABLE.id and tmp.stat = 'TEST'
          where SOME_TABLE.stat = 'PROD'
          group by SOME_TABLE.id, SOME_TABLE.stat
    )
   select * from tmp2
   union 
   select * from tmp
   ORDER BY id, pit desc
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out next monday and see how fast it is compared to the other solution. Since i'm working with potential millions of rows it's necessary for me to have a somewhat fast solution.